# Trouble posting HTML as variable in Curl

Tags: php, post, arrays, formatting, curl

I am using CURL to post an array.  It didn't work without using http_build_query().  I set one of the rows in the array like this:

```
$postVars['key']='
<table style="border-style: solid;" width="850" align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" border="3" bordercolor="#999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
      <tbody><tr> 
           <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" height="17">
';
```

and then do CURL:

```
$postURL = "https://post.xxx.org".$action;
$postData = http_build_query($postVars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

And then things break.  When I removed the semi-colon, everything worked great.  Why would I need to escape semi-colons?!

Comment: I don't understand the question - where did you remove a semi-colon?

Comment: Probably should have made a note:  I removed it from "border-style: solid;"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)